# How can i detect which fragment/tab is being utilised?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

My application consists of several tabs which all contain ListViews which are in a Fragment. These ListViews are populated using one class. I use a variable called current tab in order to detect which tab is selected and therefore the ListView can be populated to fit its requirements.

I have realised however, that when a tab is selected. The previous and next one are also loaded in order to increase the UI fluidity. I am currently unable to distinguish which listview is being operated on. As a result I am not able to retrieve its corresponding data.

onTabSelected will not do the job. I am wondering if there is some other function/method that will allow me to do this.

Comment: Would [`Fragment.isResumed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isResumed%28%29) do the trick?

Comment: Every tab implementation has a method to return the current tab. For example, TabHost has getCurrenttab(). Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Barend Thanks,  I have found out since due to this that onCreate also will work.  The problem was partly due to the structure of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override setUserVisibleHint:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        //called when fragment is visible to the user.
    }
}
```